# Very basic function gives different answer with while loop and for loop

Tags: java

The first function with a while loop:

```
public static double sum(int n){
    double sum = 0;
    while (n!=0){
        sum+=1.00/((2*n-1)*(2*n+1));
        n--;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The same function but with for loop gives another solution.

```
public static double sum1(int n){
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        sum+=1.00/((2*n-1)*(2*n+1));
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The functions calculate the series:
1/(1*3) +...+ 1/((2n+1)*(2n-1))

For some reason the function with the for loop makes the sum smaller and smaller the while function works fine.
Why the for loop solution doesn't work?

Comment: You aren't changing the value of n in the for loop function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `for` loop is using the wrong variable - it should be using `i` instead.

In your `while` loop, you were using `n` as both the control *and* the value currently represented.  You simply need to change your `for` loop to use `i`, since it represents the value you're currently iterating on.

Comment: Thank you. Hate it when it happens. Do you have some tips to trouble shoot such problems?

Comment: @TheLogicGuy:  A good IDE is a start, but in general, studying up on what each loop means and how it performs operations is a good idea too.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing `n--` in for loop and hence the difference.

You should change it to preferably:

```
public static double sum1(int n){ 
    double sum = 0; 
    for (int i=n;i>0;i--){ 
        sum+=1.00/((2*i-1)*(2*i+1)); 
    } 
    return sum; 
}
```

Comment: If you *didn't* do that, the `while` loop would run forever.

Comment: I understand that. But to get the similar result that was one quick change. Else change the loop as suggested.

Comment: I must say that the `n--` statement has nothing to do with the difference in the loops.

Comment: But it causes difference in value calculated and hence the sum too. I agree it's not the correct way to achieve it though.